# Unable to connect to Oracle from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

below is the error

> Status : Failure -Io exception: The Network Adapter could not
>   establish the connection

It's connecting from my system but unable to connect from other systems on the network.
ping command is working fine and `tnsping` is also working. any suggestion and help is very helpful.

problem resolved thanks for the support..It wasn't the database fault...It was an network issue....

Comment: can you please provide me with sqlnet.ora as well as listener.ora

Comment: # sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

Comment: # listener.ora

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = KONARK-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

Comment: add the following parameter "tcp.validnode_checking = no" or "TCP.EXCLUDED_NODES= (ip1,ip2,...)" to sqlnet.ora and restart the listener

Comment: I have added "tcp.validnode_checking = no" to my sqlnet.ora and restarted the listener. But stll its not connecting

Comment: I don't have RAC in my environment.

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna: the tnsnames.ora is not used by SQL Developer as it uses the JDBC thin driver (at least by default).

Comment: Can you post the JDBC URL that SQL Developer is using? This could also be a firewall issue.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know its not being used by SQL developer,  I wanted to check the protocol used by the database (TCP and IPC)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name From where to check the JDBC URL in SQL Developer? I can access my database on my system with sql developer.so its not sql developer issue if i'm not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a hostname resolution problem. Please try to connect to the IP address instead of the hostname.

If this is not the solution could you please post the output of the following command:

```
lsnrctl status
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
LISTENER = 
(DESCRIPTION_LIST = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = 
      (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521)
    )
    (ADDRESS = 
      (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.64)(PORT = 1521)
    )
  )
)
```

**EDIT 2:**

It turned out to be an firewall problem. See comments below.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64612/discussion-on-answer-by-ora-600-unable-to-connect-to-oracle-from-sql-developer).

Answer (score 0):

I also have experienced it, often one issue is with the firewall, and it turns out there are 3 firewall on windows that domain, private, and public firewall, of the three types domain firewall I was still on, and after I shut down, I can make a connection well.

you can search windows firewall with advanced security on start menu.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by disabling IPv6

Edited the file

> C:\oracleexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\listener.ora

and add **(IP=V4_ONLY)**

```
...
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521)(IP=V4_ONLY))
    )
  )    
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your winsock settings by running

```
C:\> netsh winsock reset
```

...in your command prompt. Make sure you run as an admin.

Reload your listener after restarting your winsock settings by typing the following command

```
C:\> lsnrctl reload
```

...in your command prompt. This should help you find the right IP to configure your SQL Developer.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem:
click on the ORCL in "Databases Detected" tab under Database Connection on the welcome page. You will then see a copy of ORCL as ORCL1 under Connection window on the left hand of SQL Developer User Interface. 
Click on the green plus sign button on the left to start a new connection. A new connection window will appear.
Don't change the connection name but change the username to the username you use for your oracle database and enter your password. you can now connect the database. It should work.

Answer (score -4):

If you are done with all above solutions, Please run Sqldeveloper as "Run As administrator" and test

Imran Barolia